# Check box outline disappears when checkbox is selected in Odoo10

Tags: css, checkbox, treeview, odoo, odoo-10

Need to add outline to checkbox permanently based on condition in tree view, By adding outline style and outline color as style in checkbox outline appears like this

[image]

but when clicked on checkbox outline disappears.
Also added custom CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
 background: red !important;
 outline:0px auto red !important;
}
```

Comment: You cant customize default one like this, why not try some custom check-boxes with pure `css` or `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

I found some example this may help you

In the account.invoice_form view :

```
  <group class="oe_subtotal_footer oe_right  invoice-residual-view">
        <field  name="residual" groups="account.group_account_user" 
            widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
  </group>
```

In our custom styles.css :

```
  .invoice-residual-view {
      font-size: 24px;
      color: #154734;  !important;
      border: 3px solid #009A44;
      font-weight: bold;
   }
      .openerp .oe_form .oe_subtotal_footer.invoice-residual-view 
      td.oe_form_group_cell {
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 3px 6px 3px 3px !important;
   }
```